# Where to find .pbix file after server shut down unexpectedly

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I was building a report in Power bi. I did not save the file yet, so by default it was named "Untitled".

Server shut down unexpectedly. After reboot I opened Power BI but. In "View recovered files" I am unable to find the one I was working on.

I'm trying to find the location where Power BI stores .ipbx files but cannot find it.

Does anybody knows is there a chance to recover my Untitled file?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Power BI stores temporary saved versions of the PBIX reports you build in the folder:

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\TempSaves\
```

e.g.

```
C:\Users\augustoproiete\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\TempSaves\
```

You should find files that look like this:

`~$Untitled (Recovered 06d01d5075934de452284d38bd96ddf6bad.pbix`

Answer (score 1):

It was hidden for me too.  I did a search on my computer for all .pbix files and the search discovered it.  I then opened file location and found it.  But I could not navigate directly to the location of the backups using Windows 10.

Comment: Could you share what was the folder it returned for you? Maybe it can help

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\<username>\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop Store App\TempSaves
```

This is the location of the .pbix auto saved files.

```
C:\Users\<username>\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop Store App\AutoRecovery
```

This is the location of any Auto Recovered .pbix files if Power Bi crashes.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are having issues opening this folder in File Explorer, you can go to menu file - Options and Settings, in Save and Recover and open the link **Open auto recovery folder**.

[image]